# API do MercadoPago

Tags: php, array, api

Estou fazendo um sistema de carrinhos aqui para testar a API do mercadopago.
Tudo esta funcionando, exceto a parte de criar o pagamento que não tenho ideia de como começar.

[API MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments)

Eu não sou muito bom em mexer com arrays, e estou aqui para pedir ajuda.
Como vira ai no site da API, ele usa array.

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "API do Mercado Pago",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "currency_id" => "BRL",                             "unit_price" => 10.00
        )
    )
);
```

Então eu tenho uma array (do carrinho) que quero passar para a da solicitação de pagamento do MP.

Carrinho, to fazendo por SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['carrinho'][$produto] = $preco; //Produto:Teste;Preço:20
$_SESSION['carrinho'][$produto2] = $preco2; //Produto:Teste2;Preço:15
```

(Usei a API do PagSeguro nele e consegui fazer funcionar)

Agora eu quero construir aquela array do MercadoPago com esses produtos do Carrinho que eu consigo assim:

```
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $produto => $preco){
```

Enfim, como eu converto a array do carrinho para a array do mercadopago?

Comment: O que esta armazenado nesse seu array carrinho? A quantidade esta armazenada tambem?

Comment: A quantidade e sempre 1

Answer (score 0):

Bom primeiro você deve passar os dados do seu carrinho para a forma que o mercadoPago pede.

```
<?php 
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $produto){
$_SESSION['items']['title']=$produto['Produto'];
$_SESSION['items']['quantity']=1;
$_SESSION['items']['currency_id']='BRL';
$_SESSION['items']['unit_price']=$produto['Preço'];                             
}

?>
```

Pronto no caso o que fiz ai, foi transformar o seu carrinho e passar para o array da forma que mercadopago quer, um array items, com titulo, quantidade...
Agora é só passar para o $preference_data.

```
$preference_data=$_SESSION['items'];
```

E é isso, ai o resto do processo, acredito que não é segredo... só seguir igual a API lá. Espero ter ajudado!! (Não testei aqui kk então pode ser que não de certo)

Comment: tal error: Uncaught exception 'MercadoPagoException' with message 'items needed' in /home/u995146358/public_html/sistemas/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php:528 Stack trace: #0 /home/u995146358/public_html/sistemas/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php(557): MPRestClient::exec(Array) #1 /home/u995146358/public_html/sistemas/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php(215): MPRestClient::post(Array) #2 /home/u995146358/public_html/sistemas/pagar.php(76): MP->create_preference(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/u995146358/public_html/sistemas/mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php on line 528

Comment: Não deu certo ?

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema. Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
$itensMP = array(array());

foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) {

    $itemMP = array(
        "id" => $items['id'],
        "title" => $items['name'],
        "quantity" => intval($items['qty']),
        "currency_id" => "BRL", 
        "unit_price" => floatval($items['price'])
    );

    array_push($itensMP, $itemMP);
}

$mp = new MP('seu_id', 'seu_token');

$preference_data = array("items" => $itensMP);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```